# Max number of if statements?

Tags: ee2, conditionals, advanced-conditionals

Folks:

I'm wondering if there's a maximum number of if statements allowed before things fall apart.

I'm evaluating if a field has content. If no, display nothing. If yes, display whatever I say. Code:

```
 {if segment_2 != "product1"}
{related_entries id="product2_specifications"}
<ul>
{if max_height}<li>Maximum height - {max_height}</li>{/if}
{if weight_in_lbs}<li>Weight - {weight_in_lbs}</li>{/if}
<li>Overall length of body - {body_overall_length}</li>
<li>Overall Width - {overall_width}</li>
<li>Inside Seat Width - {inside_seat_width}</li>
<li>Inside Height - {inside_height}</li>
{if legroom_length}<li>Legroom (Length) - {legroom_length}</li>{/if}
{if height_from_ground}<li>Height (from ground) - {height_from_ground}</li>{/if}
{if folded_dimensions}<li>Folded Dimensions - {folded_dimensions}</li>{/if}
{if capacity}<li>Capacity - {capacity}</li>{/if}
{if frame}<li>Frame - {frame}</li>{/if}
{if floor}<li>Floor - {floor}</li>{/if}
{if wheels}<li>Wheels - {wheels}</li>{/if}
{if platform_base_size} <li>Platform base size - {platform_base_size}</li>{/if}
</ul>
{/related_entries}

{if:else}

{related_entries id="product1_specifications"}
<ul>
<li>Maximum payload - {max_payload_product1}</li>
<li>Weight in pounds - {weight_in_lbs_product1}</li>
<li>Overall Length - {overall_length_product1}</li>
<li>Overall Width - {overall_width_product1}</li>
<li>Frame width - {frame_width_product1}</li>
<li>Inside Box - {inside_box_product1}</li>
{if platform_base_size} <li>Platform base size - {platform_base_size}</li>{/if}
</ul>
{/related_entries}

{/if}
```

This code works. Now, if I add a single if statement, the whole thing fails. For example, if I add:

```
{if inside_height}<li>Inside Height - {inside_height}</li>{/if}
```

to the first part, it throws an T_ENDIF error.

I've tried the ifelse plug-in with no success.

I should also note that this is a snippet placed inside a template. Template has a Switchee switch but the error also occurs with a simple if statement.

```
{exp:switchee variable = "{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
{case value="product2"}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="product2_information"}  
            {product_information}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
{/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

where product_information is the snippet.

Could very well be an easier way to do this. If so, let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wonko, you also asked if there is an easier way. Have a read of this. https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Template-partials and the linked article. You obviously have created the snippet to reuse in many templates. Using the partials approach that snippet code could sit in a layout template that multiple (page) templates use. You may find it easier.

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same issue, I can remove an if statement from anywhere and it starts to work. Did you resolve this Wonko?

Comment: What version of EE? Can you test without advanced conditionals? (without if:else) e.g. just use {if segment_2 != "product1"}...{/if} and another {if segment_2 == "product1"}...{/if}

Answer (score 3):

There is no maximum number of `if` statements. The `T_ENDIF` error you're getting means that there's either a malformed or unclosed conditional somewhere in your code.

First try removing your snippet from within the Switchee block to eliminate that, then remove/re-add your conditionals line-by-line to see exactly when the error starts.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any point where the error starts. If I eliminate an if from no matter where, it will work. If I add an if (again, no matter where), it breaks. There doesn't seem to be a pattern.